Statistical significance of non-overlapping 1-sigma confidence intervals
Is this logic correct or not?

Given two random variables, each with its own estimate of the mean and a 1-sigma (z=1, 68%) confidence interval that do not overlap with each other:
The probability of a true value being above its confidence interval is
$0.32/2=0.16$
The probability of a true value being below its confidence interval is also $0.16$
Therefore the probability of the true mean of the variable with the lower estimate being higher than its CI AND the true mean of variable with the higher estimate being lower its CI is $0.16*0.16=0.026$
Therefore the probability that the true mean value of the variable with higher estimate is in fact higher than the true mean value of the variable with lower estimate is at least $(1 - 0.026)$ ~ 97%


Welcome to CV. There are some questions about non-overlapping CIs on CV which you may find helpful. The answer to your question is no. One reason is that there is only one true value so step 5 makes no sense.

I meant to say that there were two random variables with their own confidence interval and we're trying to determine if the true mean of one is confidently higher than the other...does that change your answer?

Contemplate the situation where the SE of one variable is so small as to be negligible.  That should convince you something is wrong with ##4 and 5.

Steps 1, 2, and 3 are all correct. (z=1 corresponding to 68% is correct only for normal distributions, but let's assumne you are dealing with 2 samples from 2 normally distributed populations. Otherwise, we can ignore the z score, and say that you took 2 double-sided 68% confidence intervals (CI)).
But step 4 does not work. The true mean of the sample with the lowest mean could be inside its CI, and anyway be greater than the true mean of the sample with the highest observed mean (because it is way below its CI). And the true mean of the sample with the highest observed mean could be outside its CI, and still be above the true mean of the lowest CI. Said differently, the only way that the observed largest means is NOT actually larger is NOT that they BOTH are outside their CI's. It can happen (and not happen) under a lot of other scenarios.
And hence step 5 is incorrect as well.

Your statements 2 and 3 aren't correct. They are based on a common misconception that arises from the somewhat unintuitive way that frequentist inference works. As the Tag info on confidence intervals notes:

The interval is computed such that, if the process of drawing a sample and computing the interval were repeated identically ad infinitum, the proportion of the intervals that included the true value of the parameter would converge to $(1-\alpha)$.  This does not mean that the probability of a given interval including the true value of the parameter is $(1-\alpha)$.  Each interval either does include the true value or it does not include the true value. The 'confidence' is a property of the procedure used to compute the interval and pertains to the theoretical infinite set of such intervals.

Some relationships between lack of overlap of confidence intervals and p-values for differences in means can be found. This answer goes into some detail.

Let's use the "dogmatic" frequentist interpretation. If we took an infinite number of 68% CI's, for 68% of them, they would include the true mean. For 16% of them, the (same) true mean would be below the CI,and for 16% of them, the true (same) mean would be higher. Now, we can not afford an infinity of CI's. So instead we just randomly pick one of them; it has exactly 68% chance of containing the true mean, 16% of being above the true mean, and 16% of being below. Hence the OP's statements 2 and 3 are correct! Simple logic...
